# How send event to action in analytics in firebase - Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying send action to analytics in firebase from my app in Android but when i log on in my account in firebase and click event in analytics i don't see my actions. My action i see in DebugView in firebase.Thank you in advance for your help.
I send fragment my code:

```
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, eventTitle);
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, eventName);
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, eventName);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, params);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the events show up in Debug View, it means that everything is configured correctly and your events are being sent to the server. These events should show up straight away in Stream View too, since that uses the same mechanism as Debug View does.

In that case it's most likely waiting for the data to be aggregated into reports. This is either a matter of time, or a matter of having enough users (in the case of audiences), before the event shows up in the Analytics reports.

Also see:

- ["How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)
- [Firebase Analytics events from iOS not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416159/firebase-analytics-events-from-ios-not-showing-up)
- [How much time does it take for firebase analytics first report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report)